Pre-post design (no control) at baseline and multiple follow up times (Meta analysis)
I am working on a meta-analysis project and need advice on choosing the right statistical method. We have access to around 18 publications. The design is similar to pre-post treatment design (no control group). But we have more that two time points.
In these publications, subjects came to the clinic to check their cholesterol values at different time points (T0, T1, T3, T6) before and after treatment. Their cholesterol values were measured at T0, before receiving the treatment, and then the treatment was given to them. They were asked to return after one month (T1) for receiving the treatment and measurement again. This process repeats at three months and six months.
The research question is to compare the treatment’s effectiveness at each time point with the baseline to determine how long the treatment takes to be effective. If patients don’t show improvement after 3 months, they might consider switching to a different treatment. However, if there is no improvement at 3 months but marked improvement at 6 months, they might consider continuing with more injections of the same drug.
The publications included the results of separate paired sample tests (paired t-test or Wilcoxon signed-rank test) to compare T1 vs T0, T3 vs T0, and T6 vs T0 (paired sample before and after design).So we have access to the value of mean and sd (before and after treatment) and pvalues*
Our data is sth like (suppose we have just pre, post (T1) and post (T3):
    dat <- data.frame(study=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
         n=c( 40, 40, 10,150,150,150),
         Mean_pre=c(4,2.3,3.1,6.1,2.2,3.4),
         sd_pre=c(1,1.3,0.1,1.1,0.9,1.2), 
         Mean_post_T1=c(2,1.3,4.1,5.1,4.2,1.4),
         sd_post_T1=c(2,3.3,1.1,2.1,0.9,2.2),
         r_T0_T1=c(0.4,0.5,0.3,0.3,1.5,0.7),
         pvalue_T0_T1=c(0.001,0.03,0.006,0.05,0.004,0.01),
         Mean_post_T3=c(1,2.3,6.1,6.1,5.2,4.4),
         sd_post_T3=c(1,2.3,3.1,1.1,1.9,3.2),
        r_T0_T3=c(1.4,2.5,3.3,4.3,2,1.7),
         pvalue_T0_T3=c(0.003,0.01,0.004,0.05,0.004,0.04)
     )


  study   n Mean_pre sd_pre Mean_post_T1 sd_post_T1 r_T0_T1 pvalue_T0_T1
1     1  40      4.0    1.0          2.0        2.0     0.4        0.001
2     2  40      2.3    1.3          1.3        3.3     0.5        0.030
3     3  10      3.1    0.1          4.1        1.1     0.3        0.006
4     4 150      6.1    1.1          5.1        2.1     0.3        0.050
5     5 150      2.2    0.9          4.2        0.9     1.5        0.004
6     6 150      3.4    1.2          1.4        2.2     0.7        0.010
  Mean_post_T3 sd_post_T3 r_T0_T3 pvalue_T0_T3
1          1.0        1.0     1.4        0.003
2          2.3        2.3     2.5        0.010
3          6.1        3.1     3.3        0.004
4          6.1        1.1     4.3        0.050
5          5.2        1.9     2.0        0.004
6          4.4        3.2     1.7        0.040

 

Now, I was wondering how we should apply the meta analysis method for these type of studies? Should we also apply separate meta analysis for each comparison? Any advice on potential and right stat technique or references would be highly appreciated.

You say that the studies used "paired t-test or Wilcoxon signed-rank test". Note that the WSRt does not test the median (in spite of what one so often reads), but the pseudo-median (see e.g. wikipedia).  Note also that some studies may have used Welch t-tests rather than Student's t-tests. So a meta-analysis based on summary results (means, medians, p-values, etc.) from different tests (and with different nulls, for WSRt) seems unliekly to give meaningfull answers.

@
jginestet,
thank you so much for the great feedback. Since different tests have been applied based on different hypotheses, what would be the right statistical method for applying meta-analysis with the limited information we could collect from the publications (mean_pre, sd_pre, mean_post, sd_post, p-value of paired t-test, Wilcoxon signed-rank test, etc.)

@
jginestet, I also added a data set (as an example) into the question for more clarification.

What is the "r" column? What is this statistic? Corrleation coefficient? Then why would it be computed? What does it have to do with the p-value? ANd if the object is to measure cholesterol levels, the mean values (pre and post) which are single digit do not look at all like cholesterol levels. Can you clarify?

The obvious thing to do is a Bayesian analysis comparing to historical controls from trials with matching inclusion criteria. Effectiveness or efficacy is always as compared to what else you could have done (e.g. no treatment, start another drug...).
Cholesterol can be affected by things like regression to the mean (especially if there's a screening or baseline criterion of having high cholesterol, which I assume there is, why else start a new treatment?) and a lack of a control group is an unusual choice. With within trial variability in control group outcomes taken into account, that might things hard to judge, but that's a consequence of the trial design. The good thing is that there should be no shortage of relevant published data, as there are many studies about cholesterol interventions.
You should be to back-calculate most of the information you need from what's published, but that really depends on exactly what you have.

thank you so much for your time and comments. Our research question is not about cholesterol, but we have a similar design (multiple time points, pre and post scores, no control group, within-group). I used an example to explain our study. Unfortunately, we do not have a control group and are interested in comparing each time point with the baseline. Regarding the Bayesian method, I found an example online that includes both control and treatment groups.

Could you provide me a reference on how to use the Bayesian method when we only have access to summary statistics (including mean and SD) and no control group, or add a practical example in R to your solution? Regarding your second solution about applying regression to the mean, we have a repeated design here. Again, could you please provide me a reference or add a practical solution (or code in R) to show how the method should be applied?

One software to use that implements one particular way of doing this is the RBesT R package that can be used for the meta-analytic predictive prior approach (see e.g. this paper). An alternative approach is a model like y | se(stderr) ~ (1|study) + treatment (or variations thereof) with suitable priors e.g. via the brms R package , that implement the meta-analytic combined approach discussed in the paper.

@ Björn,  Dear Björn,
Thank you so much for your time. I appreciate your advice, but I’m still a bit confused. To help me understand your guidance fully, could you kindly provide the code with the variable names included and integrate it with the dataset I added to the question a few minutes ago?
As mentioned earlier, the research question is to compare the treatment’s effectiveness at each time point (e.g., T1, T3) with the baseline (T0) to determine how long the treatment takes to be effective.
Thank you for your assistance.

@shian requests for code are usually seen as off-topic on this site.

A few comments to start.
You say you have paired samples; therefore, the statistic is computed based on the paired differences, and not the pre, or post, datasets. So having the pre and post means and sd's is not directly usable (but there is a way to extract means and sd of the paired differences; see belo).
You also say that some studies used paired t-tests, while others used Wilcoxon Sign Rank test (WSRt). The problem is that WSRt does not use means and sd' (which are not part of computing the T statistic), that the WSRt is not a test of the median (as unfortunately way too many researchers think, and sources/textbooks mention); it is a test of the pseudo-median (i.e. the median of all the possible paired averages of the paired differences). In fact, WSRt does not use any summary statistic, and instead is based on ranks. For meta-analysis, unless you have the raw data, you can not infer the combined ranks.
Now, if you have 1 study, using a paired t-test, and with summary statistics for pre and post (i.e. each "side" of the pairs), but no statistics for the paired differences, can you derive the mean and sd of the paired differences? Yes.
Obtaining the mean of the paired difference is simple: it will simply be the difference of the means; $\displaystyle\sum_{i} (post_i-pre_i)=\displaystyle\sum_{i}post_i-\displaystyle\sum_{i}pre_i=\bar{post}-\bar{pre}$.
The sd is a bit more complex. You can not obtain it from the pre or post sd's, but you can obtain it from the p-value of the paired t-test. Let's call $d$ the difference in means (i.e. the non-standardized effect), as computed above. Then, the  one-sample t-test statistic would be $t=\dfrac {d.\sqrt {n}} {s}$. If you have the value of the t statistic, and the sample size, you can directly get the sd $s$ from it. And if you only have the p-value, you can get the table for the t-distribution of d.f. $n-1$ and look up what t statistic gives you the specific p-value. You can find an online calculator to do just this here.
So now, for all studies which used a paired t-test, you can derive the mean and sd of the paired differences (which is really what you want, and what the p-value was computed on).
What about the studies which used a WSRt? You can not use them, w/o the raw data.
Now, can you combine the paired differences of several studies? Yes. Whether you should, and under what conditions is another topic; meta-analysis is complex, and I will not tackle it here. See maybe here or here.
If you have 2 studies, both using a paired t-test, but possibly of different sample sizes $n_1$ and $n_2$, and you have the means and sd's of the paired differences of each (as per above), you can compute the mean of the combined sample (whether this combined sample is meaningful is another story: e.g. one sample was taken from the general population, the other from people already diagnosed with high cholesterol). Let's call $z$ this combined sample, and $\bar z$ its mean, then he have $\bar z=\dfrac {(n_1.\bar {x_1}+n_2.\bar{x_2})} {n_1+n_2}$.
You can also compute the sd of the combined sample $z$. Thre are many approximate formulas, but the exact formlua exists, See e.g. here for a full derivation.
$s^2_z=\dfrac {(n_1−1)s^2_1+(n_2−1)s^2_2} {n_1+n_2-1}+\dfrac {n_1.n_2.(\bar x_1-\bar x_2)^2} {(n_1+n_2)(n_1+n_2-1)}$
You now have4 the maen and sd of the combined 2 studies. If you have more than 2, just repeat the process 1 at a time.
You can now run a 1 sample t test on this combined sample. The sample size should be large enough that the CLT avoids you wondering if this combined sample is "normal enough". On the other hand, whether it makes any sense to combine these samples in the first place is a different question, which I will not touch here.
